# Looping over a list and generate serial statements in a lambda

Tags: macros, scheme, chicken-scheme

I have a macro called `compare-and-swap!`:

```
(define-macro (compare-and-swap! l x y)
  `(if (> (vector-ref ,l ,x) (vector-ref ,l ,y))
    (vector-swap! ,l ,x ,y)))
```

It works, I'm testing it like this:

```
(define v (list->vector '(5 4 3 2 1)))
(print v)
(compare-and-swap! v 1 2)
(print v)
```

I have a function that returns a list of pairs that I can call compare-and-swap! on serially to sort the whole list:

```
(batcher 8) → ((0 1) (2 3) (0 2) (1 3) (1 2) (4 5) (6 7) (4 6) (5 7) (5 6) (0 4) (2 6) (2 4) (1 5) (3 7) (3 5) (1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```

Now I wish to create a macro that generates a lambda that sorts an N element list by calling batcher and doing the `compare-and-swap!` for each pair.

For example,

```
(generate-sorter 8)
→
(lambda (l) (begin (compare-and-swap! l 0 1) (compare-and-swap! l 2 3) ...))
→
(lambda (l) (begin (if (> (vector-ref l 0) (vector-ref l 1)) (vector-swap! 0 1)) (if (> (vector-ref l 2) (vector-ref l 3)) (vector-swap! 2 3))) ... )
```

I made a function that generates the necessary code:

```
(define generate-sorter (lambda (len)
    (list 'lambda '( li ) 'begin (map (lambda (pair) (list 'compare-and-swap! 'li (first pair) (second pair))) (batcher len)))
))
```

But I don't now how to make it into a macro.

Comment: The argument to generate-sorter is always a literal number?  In this example with '8' the final `compare-and-swap!` is `(compare-and-swap! l 7 8)`?

Comment: @GoZoner: Yes, the argument is always a literal number. No, with len=8, the final `compare-and-swap!` will be on the pair `(5 6)` because that's what `(batcher 8)` returns. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a macro for this and, in particular, for the 'generate' part.  I suspect that you were thinking macro because the result of `generate-sorter` can vary from call to call and you hoped to encode the result through macro expansion.  An alternative is to capture the result in the lexical environment as such:

```
(define-syntax compare-and-swap!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ l x y)
     (when (> (vector-ref l x) (vector-ref l y))
       (vector-swap! l x y)))))

(define (generate-sorter n)
  (let ((sorters (generate-sorter n)))
    (lambda (l)
      (for-each (lambda (sorter) 
                  (compare-and-swap! l (car sorter) (card sorter)))
                sorters))))

(define sorter-8 (generate-sorter 8))
(sorter-8 <l-thingy>)
-> <sorted-l-thingy>
```